# Does shadow for directional light even work in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I can only get shadows to work for spotlight, but not for directional light.
Has anyone out there ever gotten it to work? (Using Swift, if that should matter.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the scale property of the light e.g.

```
lightNode.light?.orthographicScale = 50
```

Comment: I have not been able to find any examples of this on the web. After some trying with different values I finally got a directional shadow. Quite ugly but is it there. Once I understand what the value should be in my case I will probably get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: So for instance if you set the value to 10, it will cast shadows within a 10 metre radius of the light position.

Comment: This worked for me, however it seems like the shadows are not within X meters of the light, but instead offset in the direction the light is angled. This makes it hard to center the light node's shadows where the camera (or character is). Not sure if anyone has found a solution for this.

Comment: @cclogg You're right, it seems the shadows are applied in a radius around the direction of the light starting from its position. So I think a light with a radius of 1 will cast shadows in a 1 metre column following the light direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lightNode.light?.automaticallyAdjustsShadowProjection = true
```